# Using nodejs as a client to a Websocket server. Is it still event driven

Tags: node.js

I would like to code a performance test creating hundreds of concurrent websocket connections to a vendor's server, that will randomly send/receive messages and then hangup.

Can I use Websockets with nodejs to do this and will this be considered event driven?

To be clear, I am not building a websocket server. I basically want to use nodejs as a client to connect to an outside websocket server but create hundreds of concurrent connections that it will respond to.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're just acting as a client why do you care about the event driven part?

Comment: Because nodejs acting as client, will create hundreds of concurrent websocket connections and corresponding callbacks. If I were doing this in Java I would be using threads. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: What do you mean "will this still be considered event driven"? Who's doing the considering and why does it matter?

Comment: Very nearly everything in node is event-based though, it does its best to starve you of blocking ways to do things.

Comment: Did you used any specific npm module for this?  I'm also having same use case and right now i'm using ws  in m module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** you can use node.js and **yes** it will be event driven. All network I/O in node.js is exclusively asynchronous and event-driven.

Be aware substack's rant in the [hyperquest README](https://github.com/substack/hyperquest) about node.js core http module's connection pooling, which you will want to make sure you bypass. Presumably you'll be using a helper library such as socket.io or sock.js. Just check that they will create the number of connections you want to a single server without any pooling or throttling.